# Looking for a distribution that mean and median are different.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, median

I am looking for a distribution whose mean and median are different, preferably a distribution that share some properties with Gaussian distribution.
I kinda know that there is something called skewed distribution or alike that probably would work but I have no idea how it is defined and/or how the expectation/median is estimated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Log Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) is a natural example.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!